# Capturing part of file name in a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I am reading a csv file in pandas. The csv file has dates appended as part of its name i.e test_280323.csv.

i do some filtering on the CSV in pandas and then create data frame to store the operation of the filtering. I then write out the dataframe as a csv, at this stage I would like to append the date that was part of the original csv file that was read .so as per example my output should be :L1800_TX_with_vendor_260223.csv

the code has to be dynamic, so if date in input file changes , then output will change accordingly

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("4G_5G_TX_260223.csv",encoding = 'unicode_escape', engine ='python')

df['Carrier']=df['Carrier'].astype('string')

L1800_TX_with_vendor=df.loc[df['Carrier']=="20 MHz - EARFCN 1617"]

Comment: input file:4G_5G_TX_260223.csv

Comment: output file :L1800_TX_with_vendor_260223.csv

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are always appended following an _ and, if they always come before .csv. You can use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to split the original filename on the special symbols _ and . to get the date from the name string. Something like:

```
date = "test_280323.csv".split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

And then add the extracted string to the new file name, just before '.csv'

```
old_file_name_split = "L1800_TX_with_vendor.csv".split('.')
new_file_name = old_file_name_split[0] + date + old_file_name_split[1]
```

This is all based on the assumption that the format of the file names remain consistent.

Comment: thnaks, how Can I use the extracted  date as part of the argument for to_csv? So i can convert a dataframe into csv?

Comment: Your welcome, if your question was answered would love an upvote. And i did not get your question, what is are the arguments for to_csv ?

Comment: Hello,how can i make the code work if the filename that contains the date is dynamic, i do not want to hardcode the filename,